# Set max disk usage for Docker using WSL2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wsl-2, diskspace

On Windows 11, my docker desktop increasingly uses more disk every time I run `docker-compose up`. I tracked it to the size of the following file which is currently at about 100GB.

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data\ext4.vhdx
```

It seems on Windows you'd need to configure the Docker resource usage through [`.wslconfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configuration-setting-for-wslconfig); however, I don't see a key on the docs to adjust max disk usage.

Comment: Probably going to have to be a feature request to the Docker Desktop team and/or the WSL team.  Docker Desktop creates the VHD that `docker-desktop-data` uses, but it probably relies on WSL to do so.  It would be *possible* for Docker Desktop to manually provision the VHD with a user-configurable maximum size (at least on Windows Pro and higher), but WSL automatically provisions images with a maximum size of 250GB (although that increases to 1TB in recent WSL updates).

Comment: Thank you, @NotTheDr01ds for elaborating on that.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon the same issue today! In my case the `ext4.vhdx` had grown to 265GB.

When I attempted to continue using `docker-compose`, I recieve the following error message:

```
failed to copy files: copy file range failed: no space left on device
```

According to this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/disk-space the maxium amount of disk space should by default be either 256GB, 512GB or 1TB, depending on WSL version. So I was a little bit confused that there was no more space left on the device, especially since I had almost 500GB free space left on the disk.

Instead of using `diskpart` I choose to [Resize-VHD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/resize-vhd?view=windowsserver2022-ps) which I though would be easier, instead of messing around with diskpart.

1. Start Powershell as administrator
2. Navigate to your user folder `cd $env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data`
3. Enter the following command
   `resize-vhd -Path .\ext4.vhdx -SizeBytes 300GB`, after that I was able to continue building with `docker-compose`!

With the command above, it is possible to limit the max disk usage for Docker when using WSL2.